# Jackson Databind 2.12.7 to 2.13.5 Deserialization Issue

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

So, i have an issue i'm struggling to resolve. I have a service making a REST call to another service. Using jackson 2.12.7 all's well. Upgrading to jackson 2.13.5 the same code, config etc i'm getting this error:

`Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.rapid7.platform.ipims.domain.PlatformUser]: missing type id property '@class'`

The PlatformUser class is a straight forward POJO (and again unchanged) with the following props:

```
    private Customer customer;
    private String email;
    private String oktaUserId;
    private Long createdTime;
    private Long lastLoginTime;
    private boolean multiCustomer = false;
    private boolean externalIdp;
    private Map<String, String> userProperties = new HashMap<>();
```

We're using a Mixin to avoid deserializing userProperties Map.

Our objectMapper is setup like this:

```
private ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enableDefaultTyping(
        ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL,
        JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY
    );
    mapper.registerModule(new CoreJackson2Module());
    mapper.registerModule(new WebJackson2Module());
    mapper.registerModule(new WebServletJackson2Module());
    mapper.registerModule(new WebServerJackson2Module());
    mapper.registerModule(new Saml2Jackson2Module());
    mapper.registerModules(new Saml2Jackson2Module());
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    // handle Java 8 Datetime with JSR-310
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.addMixIn(PlatformUser.class, PlatformUserMixin.class);
    mapper.addMixIn(MapSession.class, MapSessionMixin.class);
    return mapper;
}
```

Debugging through the code i can see the objectmapper is wired in fine and that the objectMapper is setting it's valueType to a SimpleType[simple type, class PlatformUser] so things seem setup correctly but at some point something odd is happening and an AsPropertyTypeDeserializer is used and triggers the above exception (seems to be expecting the JSON to contain an @class definition/declaration, which was unnecessary previously).

So, can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks alot.

Comment: You might consider moving away from `enableDefaultTyping()` and instead specify the type handling on the class or property level using @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes

Comment: Is this Issue resolved? As I am getting issue due to deprecation of method getGenericType() from AnnotatedParameter Class and In docs it says to use "Annotated.getType() for replacement", But not working.BTW I am upgrading from 2.10.2 to 2.13.5 . https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.10.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/AnnotatedParameter.html#getGenericType--